# SQLLite update() not working, no errors in logcat. How can I diagnose the issue?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database of Web site data (ftp address, username, password, port, homedir, url etc). I can add records to the table but can't seem to update them.

I created a SiteManager Activity that loads each row and creates a WebSite object from each row. The WebSite's properties are loaded into EditTexts. The person can edit the properties and than the Update button SHOULD update the table row but it doesn't. Logcat doesn't give any errors so I'm completely at a loss, not sure where to start.

```
public class SiteManager extends Activity {
    private DBAdapter myDb;

    private EditText siteManFTPAddress;
    private EditText siteManFTPUsername;
    private EditText siteManFTPPassword;
    private EditText siteManFTPPort;
    private EditText siteManURL;
    private EditText siteManHome;
    private ImageView favIcon;
    public ListView site_list;
    private Button openBtn;
    private Button siteManUpdateBtn;
    private int _rowId;
    private String _name;
    private String _remoteHomeDir;
    private int _isLive;
    private String _address;
    private String _username;
    private String _password;
    private int _port;
    private String _url;
    private boolean _status = false;
    private String siteFolder;
    private List<WebSite> model = new ArrayList<WebSite>();
    private ArrayAdapter<WebSite> adapter;



    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.site_manager);
        site_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.siteList);
        adapter = new SiteAdapter(this, R.id.ftpsitename, R.layout.siterow,
                model);
        site_list.setAdapter(adapter);

        addListeners();
        openDb();
        displayRecords();
    }

    public void addListeners() {
        siteManFTPAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.siteManFTPAdd);
        siteManFTPUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.siteManFTPUser);
        siteManFTPPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.siteManFTPPass);
        siteManFTPPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.siteManFTPPort);
        siteManURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.siteManURL);
        siteManHome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.siteManHome);

        site_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                File rootDir = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/My Webs");
                final WebSite item = (WebSite) parent
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                _name = item.getName();
                siteFolder = rootDir.toString() + "/" + _name;
                _remoteHomeDir = item.getHomeDir();
                _isLive = item.isLive();

                String tmpaddress = item.getAddress();
                _address = tmpaddress;
                siteManFTPAddress.setText(_address);

                String tmpuser = item.getUsername();
                _username = tmpuser;
                siteManFTPUsername.setText(_username);

                String tmppass = item.getPassword();
                _password = tmppass;
                siteManFTPPassword.setText(_password);

                int tmpport = item.getPort();
                _port = tmpport;
                String portString = Integer.toString(tmpport);
                siteManFTPPort.setText(portString);

                String tmpURL = item.getUrl();
                _url = tmpURL;
                siteManURL.setText(_url);

                String tmpHome = item.getHomeDir();
                _remoteHomeDir = tmpHome;
                siteManURL.setText(_remoteHomeDir);

            }

        });
openBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openSiteBtn);
openBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent returnResult = new Intent();

        returnResult.putExtra("siteopen", "siteopen");
        returnResult.putExtra("sitename", _name);
        returnResult.putExtra("sitehome", siteFolder);
        returnResult.putExtra("sitelive", _isLive);
        returnResult.putExtra("siteremotehome", _remoteHomeDir);
        returnResult.putExtra("siteaddress", _address);
        returnResult.putExtra("siteusername", _username);
        returnResult.putExtra("sitepassword", _password);
        returnResult.putExtra("siteport", _port);
        returnResult.putExtra("url", _url);

        setResult(2, returnResult);
        finish();

    }
});
siteManUpdateBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.siteManFTPUpdate);
siteManUpdateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        _address = siteManFTPAddress.getText().toString();
        _username = siteManFTPUsername.getText().toString();
        _password = siteManFTPPassword.getText().toString();
        String port = siteManFTPPort.getText().toString();
        _port = Integer.parseInt(port);
    Toast.makeText(SiteManager.this, "Update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    myDb.updateRow(_rowId, _name,  _name, _isLive, _address, _username, _password, _port, _url);
    model.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    displayRecords();
    }
});
    }

    private void openDb() {
        myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
        myDb.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        closeDb();
    }

    private void closeDb() {
        myDb.close();
    }

    public void displayRecords() {
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
        displayRecordSet(cursor);
    }

    protected void displayRecordSet(Cursor c) {

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int rowId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID));
                _rowId = c.getInt(rowId);

                int keyNameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME);
                _name = c.getString(keyNameIndex);

                int keyHomeIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_HOME);
                _remoteHomeDir = c.getString(keyHomeIndex);

                int keyLiveIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_LIVE);
                _isLive = c.getInt(keyLiveIndex);

                int keyAddressIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ADDRESS);
                _address = c.getString(keyAddressIndex);

                int keyUsernameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_USERNAME);
                _username = c.getString(keyUsernameIndex);

                int keyPassIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_PASSWORD);
                _password = c.getString(keyPassIndex);

                int keyPortIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_PORT);
                _port = c.getInt(keyPortIndex);

                int keyUrlIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_URL);
                _url = c.getString(keyUrlIndex);
                WebSite sitesFromDB = new WebSite(_rowId, _name, _remoteHomeDir,
                        _isLive, _address, _username, _password, _port, _url);
                model.add(sitesFromDB);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if(adapter.isEmpty()){

                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class SiteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WebSite> {
        private final List<WebSite> objects;
        private final Context context;

        public SiteAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<WebSite> objects) {
            super(context, R.id.sitename, R.layout.siterow, objects);
            this.context = context;
            this.objects = objects;
        }

        /** @return The number of items in the */
        public int getCount() {
            return objects.size();
        }

        public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {
            return false;
        }

        /** Use the array index as a unique id. */
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.siterow, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.sitename);

            textView.setText(objects.get(position).getName());

            return (rowView);
        }

    }
```

DBAdapter.java

```
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String name, String homedir,
            int islive, String address, String username, String password,
            int port, String url) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;

        /*
         * CHANGE 4:
         */
        // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
        // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
        // Create row's data:
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        newValues.put(KEY_HOME, homedir);
        newValues.put(KEY_LIVE, islive);
        newValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        newValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        newValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        newValues.put(KEY_PORT, port);
        newValues.put(KEY_URL, url);
        // newValues.put(KEY_PASSIVE, passive);
        // Insert it into the database.
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `_rowId` is only ever set inside the `displayRecordSet` method where you iterate through the results from the database and set the `_rowId`:

```
int rowId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID));
_rowId = c.getInt(rowId);
```

This piece of code seems rather random to me. First you get the `columnIndex` for the `rowId`, next you get the index for this specific row and then you get the value of the column with index `rowId` and then set the `_rowId` field from this value.

I couldn't tell if the SQLite Database would be so nasty as to just return 0 if there isn't any value in the specified column, but that could definately be the problem.

So every time you get the `_rowId` set, it might just be set to 0 and when you try to update a row where `rowId = 0` nothing happens, as no index in the database can be 0.

See the [official documentation about `getInt(columnIndex)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29).

Comment: That was it. I just removed _rowId = c.getInt(rowId); and renamed rowId to _rowId. These were actually newly added and I copy/pasted from the other vars without giving any thought to what it was doing.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose issues like this, I usually add debug logs into the app. You can see these in your logcat. `Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + value);`